# How do I post data from a php form to asp.net MVC controller?

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

One department in our company is using php website. while ours department is using Asp.net MVC.

We need to pass 8 variables to php form to asp.net mvc controller. Can someone please show a simple example, how to do that?

**MVC controller.**

```
public ActionResult Booking(string Rooms,string Destination, string DepartureDate, string ReturnDate, string Adults1, string Children1, string C1Age1, string C1Age2)
{
}
```

Comment: _"php form"_ Do you mean HTML-form? PHP doesn't have any forms. If you have form in HTML that you want to post to ASP, simply add the ASP-url as the action? A post is a post, regardless where it comes from. If that's not what you're asking, please clarify the question (and add the PHP code).

Comment: Yes. It's HTML form and it's include some php code. Can i have a sample to that url?.

Comment: If you just want to post it to your ASP-code, simply add the receiving URL in the `action`-tag in the form. It doesn't matter that the page with the form contains PHP.

Comment: "It's HTML form and it's include some php code." No it doesn't. There might be some PHP used _on the server_ to _generate the resulting HTML_. But a HTML form itself (when in the browser) cannot include PHP code, because browsers don't understand PHP. If you want to post it back to an MVC endpoint, just include the URL of the endpoint as the "action" attribute of the form. How the form was created (PHP, C#, static, etc) does not matter. The only issue you might have is if there is some sort of anti-forgery token on the MVC app to try and ensure posts only come from within the MVC app.

Comment: Otherwise, the form should just look like any standard HTML form. Any fields that you want to be included in the postback must have the correct "name" attribute in the control, for MVC to match them to the action parameters - much the same as if you posted back to PHP, it would anticipate certain field names.